# save blog article for offline html5 viewing

Tags: javascript, html, offline

There are lots of different ways to save state in html5, how do you give the user the ability to decide on which articles they want to save offline and read later?

#### Edit: a bit more info...

I'm looking for a javascript/appcache solution I think. although from reading some docs I can't see any way to dynamically add urls to the app cache.

Would you need to use sql lite in the browser? or is there some better way of doing this?

Comment: Is this a programming related question or you need some tips about how to design your blog?

Comment: totally programming. just looking for the javascript/appcache or combination to allow dynamic adding of articles

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to create a manifest file for all ur urls's and resources

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cache_manifest_in_HTML5

http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/offline.html

use server side programming to create this page dynamically for each user